# Xamarin navigation drawer menu items click event not handling

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a navigation drawer contains few menu items. I am trying to implement menu item click event but click event not registering at all.

Here is my drawer :

```
   drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar  
            var toolbar = FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
           // toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.top_menus);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
            drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.SyncState();
            navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
```

This is the `setupDrawerContent` code :_

```
void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        };
    }`
```

This is `OnCreateOptionsMenu` code :

```
  public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        navigationView.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.nav_menu); //Navigation Drawer Layout Menu Creation  
      //MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.nav_menu, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //return true;
    }
```

This is `OnOptionsItemSelected` code :

```
  public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.ItemId)
        {

            case Resource.Id.nav_sangli:

                return true;
            case Resource.Id.nav_solapur:


                return true;


            default:
                break;
        }

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Problem is that debugger not even hitting `OnOptionsItemSelected`

I have tried xamarin forums but nothing worked. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong constructor `ActionBarDrawerToggle` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Your are using this one :

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, 
                DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
                Toolbar toolbar, 
                int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
                int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

Try to use this one :

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, 
                DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
                int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
                int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

So define the drawer like this :

```
 var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
```

And set your toolbar like this :

```
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Normally the event will be fired

Update :
Don't forget to add :

```
navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
```

Here is The drawer params :
Transform this line :

```
var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);
```

to :

```
`var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);`
```

Comment: with above code,  click event not firing also i lost my drawer toggle button from actionbar because you removed toolbar param. from ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Comment: Did you set the  SetSupportActionBar(toolbar); ?

Comment: I find you a tutorial : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-left-drawer-layout/

Comment: Try it, or compare to your code, maybe it will help you

Comment: So what was the problem  ?

Comment: forgotten to add navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;.  That's why my code not working. Thanks for your link

Comment: OK I will edit my answer, in case some one have the same problem

Comment: Yeh, it will be great

Comment: Don't forget, to post your answer or to validate mine to help other people :)

Comment: you still need to add toolbar param. to show drawertoggle button on your actionbar. change below  'var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);'  to                                                     
var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.drawer_open, Resource.String.drawer_close);